# Connection timedout when attempting to access any service in kubernetes

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I've create a deployment and a service and deployed them using kubernetes, and when i tried to access them by curl, always i got a connection timed out error.

Here's my yml files:

Deployment.yml

```
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: locations-service
      name: locations-service
      namespace: default
    spec:
      replicas: 2
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: locations-service
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: locations-service
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: dropwizard:latest
              imagePullPolicy: Never # just for testing!
              name: locations-service
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
                  name: app-port
                - containerPort: 8081
                  protocol: TCP
                  name: admin-port
              resources: {}
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Always
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
```

Service.yml

```
        apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: locations-service
      name: locations-service
      namespace: default
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
      ports:
      - name: "8080"
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
        protocol: TCP
      - name: "8081"
        port: 8081
        targetPort: 8081
        protocol: TCP
      selector:
        app: locations-service
```

Also i tried to add ingress routes, and tried to hit them but still the same problem occur.

Note that the application is successfully deployed, and i can check the logs from k8s dashboard
[image]

Another example, i have the following svc

```
kubectl describe service webapp1-svc
Name:                     webapp1-svc
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=webapp1
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=webapp1
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.0.0.219
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30080/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.4:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

and tried to access it using

```
curl -v 10.0.0.219:30080
* Rebuilt URL to: 10.0.0.219:30080/
*   Trying 10.0.0.219...
* connect to 10.0.0.219 port 30080 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.0.0.219 port 30080: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.219 port 30080: Connection timed out
```

Comment: which ip:port are you using for curl ?

Comment: if i tried curl ENDPOINTsIP, it will give me no route to host,
also tried the ip of the service with the nodeport, but give connection timed out

Comment: I think if a packet is not going to the host interface then there is a problem with route table. I have very limited knowledge about networking therefore, I would add a link here it might give you a reasonable answer.
https://medium.com/@ApsOps/an-illustrated-guide-to-kubernetes-networking-part-1-d1ede3322727

Comment: thanks, will take a look